# Export with displaytag

Tags: java, servlets, displaytag

I am using displaytag tag library to export the data, but my data is coming out like this:

```
<a href=../status?status_index="78190" /a>
```

However I want the HTML markup to be stripped during the export, so that only the actual data is exported.

For example, I want the only data not the url should be like:
`78190`

Code:

```
<display:table name="bulkDetails" export="true" pagesize="100" id="row" sort="list">
    <display:column title="REQUESTID" sortable="true">
        <c:url value="../Status" var="url">
            <c:param name="Status_Index" value="${row.REQUESTID}"/>
        </c:url>
        <a href=${url}>${row.REQUESTID}</a>
    </display:column>
```

My `displaytag.properties looks` like this:

```
basic.empty.showtable=true 
export.excel=true 
export.csv=true 
export.xml=false 
export.pdf=false 
export.excel.class=org.displaytag.export.ExcelView 
#export.excel.class=org.displaytag.export.CsvView 
# if set, file is downloaded instead of opened in the browser window 
export.excel.filename=report.xls 
export.csv.include_header=true 
export.csv.filename=report.csv
```

Comment: You are overriding my edit with a wrong one.

Comment: please reply as it is urgent.

Comment: Maroun : I didint get you . Please help in my question.

Comment: I am working with java my code is like :<display:table name="bulkDetails" export="true" pagesize="100" id="row" sort="list"> <display:column title="REQUESTID" sortable="true"> <c:url value="../Status" var="url"> <c:param name="Status_Index" value="${row.REQUESTID}"/> </c:url> <a href=${url}>${row.REQUESTID}</a> </display:column>
while export this data it gives me with full url like<a href/..status?status/>
but my need is only data not the full url

Comment: http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/export.html says there should be export settings set in `displaytag.properties`, do you have that? You question is still lacking detailed information such as code, configuration, etc.

Comment: I have below setting with displaytag.properties. basic.empty.showtable=true export.excel=true export.csv=true export.xml=false export.pdf=false export.excel.class=org.displaytag.export.ExcelView #export.excel.class=org.displaytag.export.CsvView # if set, file is downloaded instead of opened in the browser window export.excel.filename=report.xls export.csv.include_header=true export.csv.filename=report.csv
Do i need to add sumthing i saw the displaytag.org/1.2/export.html 
but I am not able to resolve yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to define different media types for your display and for your export columns:

```
<display:table name="bulkDetails" export="true" pagesize="100" id="row" sort="list">
    <display:column title="REQUESTID" sortable="true" media="html">
        <c:url value="../Status" var="url">
            <c:param name="Status_Index" value="${row.REQUESTID}"/>
        </c:url>
        <a href=${url}>${row.REQUESTID}</a>
    </display:column> 

    <display:column title="REQUESTID" sortable="true" media="excel">
        ${row.REQUESTID}
    </display:column>
```

Essentially this is a duplication of the same column, in browser it will have a `REQUESTID` wrapped in a link, and in the exported version it will just contain the actual number.

There's a similar question here: [DisplayTag Export and Links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680920/displaytag-export-and-links?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks a lot . I am able to view the data now.

Comment: I have another problem also As I am using display tag export option. I am able to view my excel file with 2003 office. But getting error for 2010 office . Is there any way to export .xlsx file using display tag as it may resolve my problem.

Comment: If the answer was correct, please mark it as an accepted answer. For the new problem I suggest you to post a new question.

Comment: i accepted Also I have posted as new question. kindly help for the same.